# php dom change nodeValue in anchor

Tags: php

I am trying to change NodeValue and save it to variable (or print it)

```
$html = '<html><body>
          <a href="a.html">some a</a>
          <a href="b.html">some b</a>
         </body></html>'; 
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  // ignore malformed HTML
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($html);
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $link->nodeValue = $link->nodeValue . ' --- ' . $link->getAttribute('href');
}

print_r($html);
```

should print

```
<html><body>
 <a href="a.html">some a --- a.html</a>
 <a href="b.html">some b --- b.html</a>
</body></html>
```

but it won't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it print instead?

Comment: it prints former $html (without changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually changing $html, you are changing your DomDocument variable $xml.  Instead of

```
print_r($html);
```

You need to:

```
echo $xml->saveHTML()
```

Comment: yes echo $xml->saveHTML() will print changed content but how could I store it to variable instead of print?

Comment: $html = $xml->saveHTML();